# Loop the array, and add values to start Javascript

Tags: javascript

What i need to do - simple task - I am looping the array. When `array[i] === 0;` 
i want to `+1` to `start`, it will be the same for `array[i] === 1`.
But when `array[i]` will go back (be back where it was a moment ago) i don't want to `+1` to `start`, and i did that code :

```
var start = 0;
var array = [0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1];
for (i=0; i < array.length; i ++) {
   if (array[i] === 0) {
      start += 1;
      if (array[i + 1] === 1) {
         start -= 1;
      }
   } 
   else if (array[i] === 1) {
      start += 1;
      if (array[i + 1] === 0) {
         start -= 1;
      }
   }
}
console.log(start)
```

But what if `array = [0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1];` , if `array[i]` will go back where it was a long time ago? I dont want then `+1` to `start`.

Imagine `0` and `1` like `-1` and `+1` on chart, so `console.log(start)` from `array = [0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1]` should be 5.

My code is some kind of hard coding, have you any ideas how to fix that?
Thanks for answers in advance!

**Example from comments**

`[0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1]` should produce a result of 5; you need to imagine `0 == -1` and `1 == +1`.

Then the array looks like `[-1,+1,+1,+1,-1,-1,-1,+1,-1,-1,-1,+1]` and begins this from 0 we have 5 positions where i was only 1 time.

Comment: If you use `i < array.length` then your `array[i + 1]` is going to have problems.

Comment: please add some use cases and the wanted result. whyt do you want to count the changes of `0, 1` or `1, `0, the same values, or just all `1`?

Answer (score 1):

As it looks like, you need to count the changes of the values in the array. You need to store the last value for checking the next value. If the last value and the actual value is different, you got a change and need to count.

```js
function getChanges(array) {
    var count = 0,
        last = array[0],
        i;

    for (i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (last !== array[i]) {
            count++;
            last = array[i];
        }
    }
    return count;
}

console.log(getChanges([0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]));
console.log(getChanges([0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

As @nurdyguy has pointed out, your call for `array[i+1]` will be out of bounds for the last element. I have flipped the comparison to the previous element and started the loop on the second element to counter this.

You seem to be calculating `+=1` regardless of the binary result then only `-=1` when the next element in the array differs so essentially i think you have the opposite of what you are looking for :

```
var start = 0;
var array = [0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1];

for (i=1; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (array[i] === array[i-1]) {
    start++;
  }
}
```

Now if you want to calculate the times the element changes from each step then you can just flip the logical:

```
var start = 0;
var array = [0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1];

for (i=1; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (array[i] !== array[i-1]) {
    start++;
  }
}

console.log("The result is: " + start) // The result is: 5
```

I think this is what you are after, please elaborate if not.

**Edit:**

Apologies, I did test your other array and the result was also 5.

What you are looking for is this then:

```
var start = 0;
var array = [0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1];

for (i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
  start += array[i];
}

console.log("The result is: " + start) // The result is: 5
```

If the array of 0 and 1 is only as an example then use a logical:

```
var start = 0;
var array = [0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1];

for (i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
  array[i] == 1 ? ++start : +-start;
}

console.log("The result is: " + start) // The result is: 5
```

or:

```
var start = 0;
var array = [0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1];

for (i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (array[i] == 1) {
    ++start 
  }
}

console.log("The result is: " + start) // The result is: 5
```

If the array becomes `[-1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,1]` like you said then the result is not `5`, it's `-3`?

Comment: result 5 should be from array = [0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1],

Comment: you need to imagine 0 and 1 like -1 and +1 on chart, so console.log(start) from array = [0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1] should be 5.

Comment: and then the arrat looks like (-1, +1, +1, +1, -1, -1, -1, +1, -1, -1, -1, +1) and begins this from 0 we have 5 positions where i was only 1 time

Comment: @bafix2203please take a look at my edit, I Think I understand. I will edit this extra information in to your question, as it was essential clarity to the scope of the question.